# Issue with npm and Node.js version compatibility in Vite project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, vite

I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my Vite project using npm. I've recently updated Node.js to version 18.16.0, and now I'm getting the following error:**The specified module could not be found.
\?\C:\Users\Riaj\OneDrive\Desktop\Program\Backend\Hitesh choudury class\fullstackbasicApp\frontend\node_modules@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node**.

I've tried the following steps to troubleshoot:

- Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json or yarn.lock file.
- Reinstalled dependencies using npm install.
- Checked compatibility of project dependencies with Node.js 18.16.0.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

I want to make fullstack apps with vite

Comment: `error:The specified module could not be found.`  Read the rest of the error, it should be saying somewhere what it can't find.

Comment: Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\Riaj\OneDrive\Desktop\Program\Backend\Hitesh choudury class\fullstackbasicApp\frontend\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
 this is the full error

Comment: the first thing I would do is remove spaces from folder names

Comment: `OneDrive`,  This is the second time today I've seen somebody trying to run node on a `OneDrive`, I would strongly suggest not..  Try `npm install` into a normal folder..

Comment: Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\F:\Program\Backend\Hiteshchouduryclass\fullstackbasicApp\frontend\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node

Answer (score 2):

Check out this GitHub discussion, this issue was resolved

https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/3612#issuecomment-1538380963

> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable
> - Remove `node_modules` directory
> - Remove `package-lock.json` file
> - `npm cache verify`
> - Restart the machine
> - `npm install`

Comment: While the URL may answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Links can be blocked by web filters, and can go offline.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, **installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64)** helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, after installing vc_redist.x64.exe it was solved

[vc_redist.x64.exe install](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)

this is for windows x64